# jQuery mobile button sometimes only gets selected but no page transition happens

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

In a Phonegap Application with jQuery mobile, there are times that I click a button but it only gets selected  and doesn't transition to the other page, it has happened even with the back buttons that are generated automatically by the library, I have to click it again to get it work. It's strange because the problem is not always reproducible. At first I thought it was the phone but I tried in another one and the same thing happened.

- jQuery mobile 1.4.3
- Phonegap (Cordova) 3.5.0
- Android  4.4.2 and 4.1.2

HTML:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Back">
<h1>Test</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="content">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, do you fix this problem? I have the same problem and don't know how fix it.

Comment: @Carra still no luck yet. It seems it has something to do with Android thinking that you are actually not tapping but touching. For example if you touch a button (leave the finger there for a second and then release) click event doesn't fire.

Answer (score 0):

After diferents test, I discard the use of rel="back".
My button are this:

```
<a href="#home" data-icon="arrow-l" data-direction="reverse"   data-role="button"  data-inline="true">Back</a>
```

Whithout the 'rel="back"' works but sometimes when click the button selected and not back, and when click one more time the back button works.

Finally I catch the tap and execute the change of page manually

```
$('a[data-direction="reverse"]').on('tap', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        $('#loading').hide();   // stop loading icon in case of click back when loading data                 
        $.mobile.changePage($(this).attr("href"),{transition:'fade'});
});
```

Comment: Sorry I forget event.preventDefault();